# The fundamental loopoid?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

Let $X$ be a homotopy type (modeled as either a topological space or a simplicial set). We can construct a category as follows: The objects are maps $f,g : S^1 \to X$. A morphism $f \to g$ is a map $S^1 \times I \to X$ which restricts to $(f,g)$ on the boundary. We identify two such morphisms if they are homotopic relative to the boundary. In particular, if $f,g$ are homotopic as maps $S^1 \to X$, then they are isomorphic in this category. Let us call it the  **the fundamental loopoid.**

The fundamental loopoid is far from trivial. For example, if $X = BG$ for a finite group, then the fundamental loopoid is Morita equivalent to the Drinfeld double algebra with basis $(h,g) \in G^2$ and multiplication given by
$$(h_1,g_1)(h_2,g_2) = \delta_{g_1h_2g_1^{-1}}^{h_1} (h_1,g_1g_2).$$
This algebra is always semi-simple when $X=BG$. For small groups, computing its representation category is tractible. For example, when $G = S_3$, it has eight simple representations.

> **Question:**  Has this category been computed for any other examples? I am particularly interested in cases when $X$ has non trivial $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$.

Comment: This is the fundamental groupoid of the free loop space on $X$, no?

Comment: And if $X = BG$ it's the quotient groupoid $G/G$ of the conjugation action of $G$ on itself. In general it only depends on the homotopy $2$-type of $X$ and in principle one could give a complete description of it in terms of your preferred model of homotopy $2$-types. This would answer a question of Kevin Carlson's on math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589288/what-exactly-is-the-fundamental-group-of-a-free-loop-space

Comment: @KevinCarlson: Ohhh yeah, obviously! Thanks for pointing that out.